# Webdriver-Perl : How to install Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, centos7

I'm trying to execute a simple test , it's written with **perl**.

> perl --version
>   This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

This is the test code:

```
 use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
 use Test::More "no_plan";
 use Test::Exception;

 my $sel = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( host => "myadress",
                                port => xxxx,
                                browser_name => "internet explorer",
                                browser_url => "my_url" );

$sel->open_ok("url/login.php");
$sel->type_ok("login", "mylogin");
$sel->type_ok("password", "mypassword");
$sel->click_ok("id=log_in");
$sel->wait_for_page_to_load_ok("30000");
```

This test named **test.pl**
When I execute **~]# perl test.pl**

> Can't locate Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/ve BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at perl.pl line 1

I'm so confused about this , what can i do to execute this test?
Thank you for your test.

Comment: Have you installed the module this depends on?

Comment: Try to check if you have it installed using: perldoc -l Selenium::Remote::Driver

Comment: I got this : No documentation found for "Selenium::Remote::Driver".